# CSS animation only works as intended when I re-save my style.css file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, animation

I wrote a program that prompts the user to enter a temp and have that temp be reflected on a vertical bar that I have animated to change the height depending on the value given. The weird issue I'm running into is that it doesn't work, but if I re-save my style.css file after entering a value it works as intended. From there, if I enter subsequent values it'll jump to the expected heights while skipping the animation entirely.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="temp-container">
            <div class="temp-indicator" id="indicator-1"></div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="changeTemp()">ENTER TEMP</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
:root {
    --temp-start: 0%;
    --temp-end: 0%;
}
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 50px;
}

.temp-container {
    width: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 50px 0px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  .temp-indicator {
    width: 100%;
    mask:linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    border-radius: 25px;
  }

  .slide-to-temp {
    animation: slideToTemp 1s forwards;
  }

  @keyframes slideToTemp {
    from {height: var(--temp-start);}
    to {height: var(--temp-end);}
  }


  .temp-indicator::before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, lightblue 75%);
  }
  
  #indicator-1 {
    height: var(--temp-start);
  }


  button {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 800;
    border: 5px solid black;
  }
```

```js
let indicator = document.getElementById("indicator-1");
let root = document.documentElement;

function changeTemp() {
    let inputTemp = prompt("Enter a temp:");
    root.style.setProperty("--temp-end", `${inputTemp * 2}%`);

    indicator.classList.add("slide-to-temp");
}
```

The logic seems to check out, but clearly I'm missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is something is modifying the CSS file, so you have to resave it to put back your version. What do you see if you look at the file in the Sources panel of DevTools before re-saving?

Comment: Now it's not working unless I re-save my style.css three times. When it worked my .css file name was style.css?_cacheOverride=1706836459719 within the Sources panel of DevTools.

Comment: Sounds like you have JavaScript that's adding a cachebuster to the `link` tag.

Comment: When you view the contents of that before re-saving, does it contain the correct CSS?

Comment: It seems to be? I'm still relatively new to all this and not 100% sure what to look for, but I didn't notice any differences.

Comment: Then I can't think of a reason why it's not working. When you select an element in the Elements panel, do you see the correct style in the sidebar?

Comment: I entered 20, which should set the --temp-end to 40%, which it did. Saw it reflected on the Elements page with the bounds of the div being where the animation should have gone to, but there was nothing visually reflected until I re-saved my style.css a couple times.

Comment: Where do you remove the class slide-to-temp?

Answer (score 0):

Just change  `--temp-start: 1%;  --temp-end: 1%;` and its working.
0 * any number gives 0. So `--temp-start: 0%;` and `root.style.setProperty("--temp-end",` ${inputTemp * 2}%`);` will result always 0.Also add  `transition: all;` to `.slide-to-temp` class

```js
let indicator = document.getElementById("indicator-1");
      let root = document.documentElement;

      function changeTemp() {
        let inputTemp = prompt("Enter a temp:");
        root.style.setProperty("--temp-end", `${inputTemp * 2}%`);

        indicator.classList.add("slide-to-temp");
      }
```

```css
:root {
        --temp-start: 1%;
        --temp-end: 1%;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 50px;
      }

      .temp-container {
        width: 50px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 50px 0px;
        background: black;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        border-radius: 25px;
      }

      .temp-indicator {
        width: 100%;
        mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
        border-radius: 25px;
      }

      .slide-to-temp {
        animation: slideToTemp 1s forwards;
        transition: all;
      }

      @keyframes slideToTemp {
        from {
          height: var(--temp-start);
        }
        to {
          height: var(--temp-end);
        }
      }

      .temp-indicator::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(red, lightblue 75%);
      }

      #indicator-1 {
        height: var(--temp-start);
      }

      button {
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 800;
        border: 5px solid black;
      }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="temp-container">
        <div class="temp-indicator" id="indicator-1"></div>
      </div>
      <button onclick="changeTemp()">ENTER TEMP</button>
    </div>
```